# codeigniter active record where_in

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

i'm using codeigniter 2xx.
Mysql table:

```
create table hobby (
id int,
school varchar,
classes varchar,
basketball text,  {12,15,17...}
football text,  {12,18,20...}
swimming text {11,15,....}
);
```

i intend to store the student id as serialized(array(integer)) in the mysql table fields like basketball, football and swimming.
I want to find out a particular class student id (eg. 12) if he has join any hobby or more than 1 hobby using codeigniter active records method but stuck. Below is my code:

```
$this->db->select('basketball','football','swimming');
$this->db->or_where('school', $data)->where('classes', $classid)->where_in($student_id, 'basketball');
$this->db->or_where('school', $data)->where('classes', $classid)->where_in($student_id, 'football');
$this->db->or_where('school', $data)->where('classes', $classid)->where_in($student_id, 'swimming');
$query = $this->db->get('hobby');
```

Or is there a better way to store & handle the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `student_hobby` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hobby_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `hobby` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

set hobby student:

```
$this->db->insert('student_hobby', array('student_id' => 12, 'hobby_id' => 1));
```

select student who has 1 or more hobby:

```
$this->db->select('student.*, hobby.name');
$this->db->from('student_hobby');
$this->db->where('studend_id', 12);
$this->db->join('hobby', 'hobby.id = student_hobby.hobby_id');
// join to your existing student table. Fields `school` and `class` should be in `student` table.
$this->db->join('student', 'student.id = student_hobby.student_id');
$result = $this->db->get();

if($result->num_rows()) {
      // if student has one or more hobbies
}
```